# Feature creation (Cucumber tests)

Tags: cucumber, feature-selection

Project description is asking to create feature and step definition for edit recipe but feature is already given? Should we still need to create/add some features?

Comment: Does your feature has a scenario in it?

Comment: You need to link both features n stepdefination